# How to get github username in Firebase Github Auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get username of the user while authenticating using Firebase Github Auth. but I am not able to get it. I get all the user info except an username
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext, useEffect } from "react"
import { auth, createUserProfileDocument } from "../config/fbConfig"

const AuthContext = createContext()

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)

  const provider = new auth.GithubAuthProvider()
  provider.addScope("read:user")
  const githubSignIn = () => {
    return auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
  }

  const githubSignOut = () => {
    return auth().signOut()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      // setCurrentUser(user);
      if (userAuth) {
        const useRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth)
        useRef.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
          console.log(snapShot)
          setCurrentUser({
            id: snapShot.id,
            ...snapShot.data(),
          })
        })
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(userAuth)
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    githubSignIn,
    githubSignOut,
  }

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}> {children} </AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

fbConfig.js file code

```
export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth) => {
  if (!userAuth) return
  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`)
  const snapShot = await userRef.get()

  if (!snapShot.exists) {
    const { email, photoURL, providerData } = userAuth
    const createdAt = new Date()
    getGitHubUserData(providerData[0].uid)
      .then(async (gitHubUserData) => {
        const username = gitHubUserData.login
        try {
          await userRef.set({
            email,
            photoURL,
            createdAt,
            displayName: providerData[0].displayName,
            username,
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message)
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error("Don't forget error handling: ", err))
  }
  return userRef
}
```

Anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When authenticating a GitHub user, Firebase will store the following information in the authenticated user's ID token (`auth.currentUser.providerData`):

```json
{
  // User's GitHub display name
  displayName: "Display Name",
  // User's public email address, null when private/out-of-scope
  email: null,
  // Phone numbers aren't applicable. Always null.
  phoneNumber: null,
  // Link to user's GitHub profile image, may be hosted on Gravatar
  photoURL: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/GITHUB_ID?v=4",
  // Always "github.com" - used to identify this ProviderData entry
  providerId: "github.com",
  // Numeric Github User ID
  uid: "GITHUB_ID"
}
```

Note here, that none of this data provides the user's username on GitHub. This is mainly because a GitHub user can change their username at will and GitHub will not send out "new username" notifications to any connected apps along with [other side effects](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-user-account-settings/changing-your-github-username).

With this in mind, to resolve a GitHub user ID to their username, known on GitHub as their `login`, you can query the GitHub API with the user's ID:

```
https://api.github.com/user/{idOrLogin}
```

Accessing this data with a function gives:

```js
async function getGitHubUserData(githubIdOrLogin) {
  return fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/user/${githubIdOrLogin}`,
    { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' } }
  )
    .then((response) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        const err = new Error();
        err.response = res;
        if (res.status === 403 && res.headers.get('X-RateLimit-Remaining') == '0') {
          const resetsAtMS = Number(`${res.headers.get('X-RateLimit-Reset')}000`);
          err.message = `Rate limit exceeded, try again in ${Math.ceil((resetsAtMS-Date.now())/60000)}m`;
          err.code = "github/rate-limit-exceeded";
          err.resetsAt = resetsAtMS;
        } else if (res.status === 404) {
          err.message = `Could not find user data for github:${githubIdOrLogin}`);
          err.code = "github/not-found";
        } else { // add other cases if you want to handle them
          err.message = `Unexpected status code: ${res.status}`;
          err.code = "github/unknown";
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }

      return res.json();
    });
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```js
const githubProviderData = auth.currentUser
  .providerData
  .find((pd) => pd.providerId === 'github.com');

getGitHubUserData(githubProviderData.uid)
  .then((githubUserData) => {
    // githubUserData.login will be their username
    // githubUserData.html_url will be a link to their profile
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error('Don\'t forget error handling: ', err));
```

**Notes:**

- When using this API anonymously (i.e. without authentication) you are subject to (at the time of writing) a limit of 60 public API calls per hour for that IP address. GitHub's rate-limit-exceeded response code is `403 Forbidden`. If you tie in the user's authentication token, this limit bumps up to 5000 calls/hour for that user. If you use a application/server authentication token, this limit bumps up to 12500 calls/hour. See [GitHub's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/rate-limits-for-github-apps) for more details.
- There are node packages available that consume the GitHub API like the official [`@octokit/core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octokit/core), [`@octokit/request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octokit/request) and [`@octokit/rest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octokit/rest%60) packages if you are doing more with the user's GitHub than just getting their username. See the [GitHub request documentation](https://github.com/octokit/request.js/#request) for more info. BVy using `@octokit/request`, the above code could be simplified to just (but errors are handled differently):

```js
request('GET /users/{username}', { username: idOrLogin })
```

Comment: Hello there,
thanks for your answer. Now, I am getting a username.
Can you please tell more about this "If you tie in the user's authentication token, this limit bumps up to 5000 calls/hour for that user?" 
How to do that? Do I need to use my GitHub account authentication token or signed up user authentication token(if yes how to get signed up user token)

Comment: I added the fbConfig.js file code. Can you please check? Am I doing it correctly?